# How To Create A Dynamic 2D Rope In Unity?

Tags: unity, rope-physics

I'm trying to create a 2D rope in Unity that is fixed at one end and other is moving up and down to pick up objects just like a crane.

I've tried adding a cube and making more instances of it, adding a parent-child relation and hinge joint between them when I press the Down arrow.

It worked, but when I tried to move them sideways a big noise is generated.
I then tried with a spring joint, but that didn't work.

Comment: Are you using custom physics or a built-in engine? Could you describe further what you mean by "big noise"? Is the simulation unstable?